# How to rebuild a tableselect after submit?

Tags: 7, hooks

i've a tableselect showing list of books orders with dates (of the order) i've just added two date fields to "sort" books by 2 dates. So the user should select date 1, date 2 and submit, that makes appear only books sold in this date interval. The think is; i can dsm the array of books between two dates (the query works) but the "rebuild" part doesn't work.

Here is my code :

```
function filtrer_commande_par_date_submit($form, &$form_state){

//getting the values from two simple date pickers
$date_1 = $form_state['values']['date_order1'];
$date_2 = $form_state['values']['date_order2'];

$result = db_query("SELECT b.uid, b.entity_id, b.date_sold,     c.username_client, edit.field_edit_target_id,ed.username_auto, title.field_title_value, pr.field_price_value FROM {bibliotheque} as b
            left join {clients} as c on c.uid = b.uid
            left join {field_data_field_edit} as edit on edit.entity_id = b.entity_id
            left join {editeur} as ed on ed.uid = edit.field_edit_target_id
            left join {field_data_field_title} as title on title.entity_id = b.entity_id
            left join {field_data_field_price} as pr on pr.entity_id = b.entity_id
            WHERE STR_TO_DATE(b.date_sold, '%d/%m/%Y') between 
           '$date_1' and 
           '$date_2'
        ")->fetchAll();

  // dsm($resultat); <==== this shows right result.

  $rows_date = array();

        foreach ( $resultat as $new_res ){

            $rows_date [] = array(
                'client'=> $new_res->username_client,
                'livres'=> $new_res->field_titre_latin_value,
                'id_livre' => $new_res->entity_id,
                'editeur'=> $new_res->username_auto,
                'date'=> $new_res->date_achat,
                'prix'=> $new_res->field_prix_value,
                'devise' => $new_res->devise_ed
            );
        }

        // $form_state['liste_tableau']['#options'] = array(
        //  '#options' => $rows_date             <=== doesn't work
        // );
        // $form_state['values']['liste_tableau'] = $rows_date; <=== doesn't work too
        $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
    }
```

I want to make #options of tableselect (liste_tableau) take the new row ($rows_date) with the sorted valus by date_1 & date_2 but the tableselect doesn't change.

Please any help ?